# Learning d3.js for data visualisation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to start learning to make data visualisations (as side project in my PhD) preferably with the `D3.js` package. I do not have `java`-experience but i do have a background in OOP as i mostly work in `python`. As such, I was wondering what's the best way to learn working with d3 and which environment one could recommend me.

Comment: To learn `D3.js` you can start with the official [documentations and examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki). As for IDEs, there are lots of them, just choose the one that makes you comfortable. I use [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=php) for development and [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) for quick editing. P.S. `Java` has nothing to do with `Javascript`.

Comment: as @Adnan points out, Java and Javascript are not the same.

Comment: Please move the question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - while it is related to D3, it's not really about a certain bug/feature that you would like solved but about how to approach D3... in this case it is always recommended to move to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I find [this site](https://www.dashingd3js.com/table-of-contents) to be useful. besides their commercial deviation and dragging, it is a well formed one for newbies with focus.

Comment: yes please change Java to JavaScript. it's like comparing ham to hamsters.

Comment: A nice blogpost about d3 resources which considers the learning curve: https://engineering.eventbrite.com/d3-js-resources-to-level-up/

Comment: Here's a YouTube tutorial that covers D3.js from the ground up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jvoTV54nXw This covers how to make a scatter plot, bar chart, and line chart.

Comment: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-d3-js is a great place to find best online D3.js tutorials. All the tutorials here are submitted and recommended (upvoted like SO) by the programming community.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since I recently found it, I'd recommend working with http://phrogz.net/js/d3-playground/ as well for a sandbox in which to trial out and learn how the pieces can work together.

Answer (score 37):

Scott Murray's tutorials are a great starting place: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/

Regarding environments, you might find this useful: http://tributary.io. It's an interactive coding editor designed to help you learn d3.

Comment: I can't get that site to work. I'm sure it's because you start out with the assumption that you are going to work with an SVG...? I don't know... but I spent 30-45 minutes and was lost... I'm trying to wrap my head around D3 and stumbling blindly...

Comment: @randomblink sorry to hear that. Did this site http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3 not load for you? I'd definitely encourage you to give it a try, Scott's material is fantastic.

Comment: Scott's site is great. I can wrap my head (almost) around what he is writing about. But I'm trying to create timelines. And I can't find any straight up timeline D3 tutorials. Everything wants to use X and Y on a timeline. I want to put a dot on a timeline at a specific event and I can't find an example. I've purchased some tutorial videos, books, and more. And maybe I need to step back from my timeline thinking and just get familiar with the 'other' D3 concepts and THEN go back to time... I don't know. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 8):

Scott Murrays website is a good first start http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/.

Once done with that, I might recommend you take a look at this website http://techslides.com/over-1000-d3-js-examples-and-demos/, it lists 1000 examples of d3. You can usually copy the javascript data and code and play around with it locally on your own computer.

You can also try to take one of these plots and see if you can reconstruct it.

The reason why I found this to be useful is that you need to be able to recognize the errors that d3 throws at you. It's the moments that you  have no idea why there is an error that are troublesome. By having an example that you are reconstructing you guarantee yourself of a copy of code that works such you might be able to more easily correct yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a few tutorials for beginners to learn both **Javascript and data visualization**:

http://blog.vida.io/2014/06/23/coding-visualization-tutorial-1-variables/ http://blog.vida.io/2014/06/23/coding-visualization-tutorial-2-functions/

I find the first four tutorials from wiki very useful to learn **D3 fundamentals**:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials

Introduction, Three Little Circles, Thinking with Joins, How Selections Work.

My team runs https://vida.io. We use template approach to d3 and allow user to quickly create working document, upload new data, and bind data to document through GUI editor. Check out examples to get started:

https://vida.io/explore

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of resources that I'm using to learn d3js.  The official site can be a bit overwhelming for someone new to web development so here's a few more:

**Tutorials**

- Official D3js website has a list of good examples and tutorials [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials)
- Square has a great quick intro to D3 when they onboard [here](http://square.github.io/intro-to-d3/)
- Christophe Viau has a good one page intro [here](http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/)
- Jerome Cukier's "Hello World" in D3, which goes into more detail of setting up your environment available [here](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2012/09/04/getting-to-hello-world-with-d3/)
- Scott Murray (alignedleft) explains things very well.  He's also the author of 'Interactive Data Visualization', which I highly recommend.  Tutorial [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/)

**Reference**

- You're going to see a lot of different d3 functions and wonder what they do.  Use the official API [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference).

Answer (score 0):

I've been through many of the d3.js tutorials and found them to be confusing. When a person is not yet very familiar with HTML and CSS, they need a bit more explanation of the details. Those details are better presented in NRecursions:
Part1: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2014/11/getting-your-head-around-d3js.html
Part2: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2014/12/getting-your-head-around-d3js-part2.html