# Issue in fetching data from nested json to construct bar graph in d3

Tags: d3.js

here is the json data..
[
           {
            "month":"2016-01",
            "top_services":[
                     {
                    "domain":" EESEL-PROD-XCRM",
                    "service":" Subscriber-1_0",
                    "operation":" getSubscriberProfile",
                    "total_trans":333646
                 },
                 {
                    "domain":" EESEL-PROD-XCRM",
                    "service":" ProductQuery-3_0",
                    "operation":" listSubscriberProducts3",
                    "total_trans":242797
                 },
                 {
                    "domain":" ELYSEES-PROD",
                    "service":" GetCachedNetworkSettings-2_0",
                    "operation":" electroencephalographic",
                    "total_trans":242123
                 },
             ]
           }
        ]

Comment: what you tried so far... What you want to show on x-axis and y-axis. How the bar chart look like??

Comment: I tried fetching json data via ajax call and constructed bar chart with simple json data (key-value).. i can fetch nested json data,but not able to plot bar graph with the data having x-axis as operation name and y-axis as total transaction..

Comment: Not able to plot bar graph for this json data..please help
[
{
 "month":"2016-01", 
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Al Montoya",
      "saves": 15.5
    },
    {
      "name": "Alex Stalock",
      "saves": 14.7
    },
    {
      "name": "Anders Lindback",
      "saves": 12.4
    },
    {
      "name": "Anton Khudobin",
      "saves": 21.4
    }
    ]
    }
    ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data=[ { "month":"2016-01", "children": [ { "name": "Al Montoya", "saves": 15.5 }, { "name": "Alex Stalock", "saves": 14.7 }, { "name": "Anders Lindback", "saves": 12.4 }, { "name": "Anton Khudobin", "saves": 21.4 } ] } ] ;
data=data[0].children;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
    //.ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  //if (error) throw error;


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.saves; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.saves); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.saves); });
//});

function type(d) {
  d.saves = +d.saves;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

First of all we need to convert the data into needed format, i.e. array of objects, by

```
var data=[ { "month":"2016-01", "children": [ { "name": "Al Montoya", "saves": 15.5 }, { "name": "Alex Stalock", "saves": 14.7 }, { "name": "Anders Lindback", "saves": 12.4 }, { "name": "Anton Khudobin", "saves": 21.4 } ] } ] ;
data=data[0].children;
```

So now `data` is having array of objects.Hope you can understand the remaining.

Comment: Thank You very much ..I could plot data  on y-axis given in lakhs,but how to figure it out in numbers on y axis ..
ex:var data=[ { "month":"2016-01", "children": [ { "name": "Al Montoya", "saves": 333646 }, { "name": "Alex Stalock", "saves": 242797 }, { "name": "Anders Lindback", "saves": 242123 }, { "name": "Anton Khudobin", "saves": 240055 } ] } ] ;

Comment: we can change it to any format like in Thousands or lakhs or etc. In which format you want to show it. There is a function type() in that you can divide the value with 10 or 100 or 1000 or 10000. then Y-axis value will be changed accordingly. k na.

Comment: Thank you very much..i wanted to show in lakhs,, but bit confusing of where to use the function type().

Comment: After `data=data[0].children;` line place `data.forEach(function(d){type(d);});` and in `type(d)` divide with 1000 `d.saves=+d.saves/1000`. k

Comment: when i move the mouse over the graph i am getting the data which is their in saves field ,but wanna convert into percentage..please help me..Example 242797 into 24.2797%..

Comment: To learn anything new, we just have to keep on explore, analyze.Then we can digest the things. D3 needs JavaScript knowledge and algorithmic approach. There are so many tutorials we can refer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025374/learning-d3-js-for-data-visualisation, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=d3js+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-3XBVoOHPMmSuASt24OQCA#q=d3js+tutorial+for+beginners

Comment: I have a question on Ubuntu with respect to installing hadoop can I ask?

Comment: I don't have idea on hadoop, one of my friend is working on it. If you say that question I'll ask him.

Comment: I Wanted to install hadoop software on ubuntu 14.04 ..but when i try the command sudo apt-get install openssh-server..I am getting the error as

Package ssh is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: openssh-client

E: Package 'ssh' has no installation candidate

I tried command sudo apt-get update..But still same problem arises ..Please help me..

Comment: Error is:Package ssh is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: openssh-client E: Package 'ssh' has no installation candidate

Comment: Present I'm outside of office. I'll get it to you once I discuss with my friend.

Comment: Good evening... Great, Yesterday I didn't met him. well, solved ah. Good

Comment: I have a question on sql queires can i ask?

Comment: I have two datasets:

    User information (id, email, language, location)
    Transaction information (transaction-id, product-id, user-id, purchase-amount, item-description)

Given these datasets, I want to find the number of unique locations in which each product has been sold.

Comment: Okay, transactioninfo has user_id which is primarykey of userinformation... Well, I'm working on it. Will get it to you. ASAP

Comment: SELECT p.product-id, count(distinct u.loc) unique-loc-counts FROM User Information u, transaction information t WHERE t.user-id=u.user-id GROUP BY p.product-id;
 Try this

Comment: Okay. No problem. I've to ask my friend. Bcoz I don't have any exp on it.

Comment: Thank u..here is the question:)

Comment: Given dml mapping how to do pig transformation to perform filtering on raw data so that only record_type='01' is selected

Comment: DML Mapping:

  
                        string('\x01')record_status= NULL("");
                        string('\x01')check_sum= NULL("");
                        string('\x01')call_reference= NULL("");
                        string('\x01')exchange_id= NULL("");
                        string('\x01')intermediate_record_number= NULL("");

Comment: Yeah! Tell me. Free now.

Comment: program to Aggregate all the synonyms of a word

Comment: i did using map reduce but stuck

Comment: public class synonymsMapper1  extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text,Text > {
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,
                  InterruptedException {
           StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",");
           while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                  word.set(itr.nextToken());
                  context.write(key, word);
           }
    }
}

Comment: public class synonymsReducer1  extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,Text>
{
    private Text result = new Text();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
    Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String translations = "";
        for (Text val : values)
        {
            translations += "|"+val.toString();
        }
        result.set(translations);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

Comment: A small change in the question(key,value pairs)
input:
tv
house
radio
dhoordharshan
home
akashavani

output:
tv dhoordharshan
house home
radio akashavani

Comment: input:
tv,
house,
radio,
dhoordharshan,
home,
akashavani

output:
tv- dhoordharshan,
house- home,
radio -akashavani.

Comment: Okay, How could we map words, is there any reference for mapping synonyms. If we take tv as input and search for synonym using any file or

Comment: yeah tv,radio,house are the keys..
for tv value is dhoordharshan,
for house value is home,hut
for radio value is akashavani,

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         SynonymTable synTable = new SynonymTable();
         synTable.registerSynonym("tv","dhoordharshan, television");
         synTable.registerSynonym("radio","akashavani");
         synTable.registerSynonym("house ","home");
         System.out.println("tv-"+synTable.getSynonyms("tv"));

     }
}

class SynonymTable {

private Map<String, Set<String>> synonymTable = new HashMap<>();

public Set<String> getSynonyms(String word) {
    return synonymTable.get(word);
}

public void registerSynonym(String word, String... synonymsOfWord) {
    for (String syn : synonymsOfWord) {
        putSynonymTable(word, syn); // synonym(word) = syn
        putSynonymTable(syn, word); // synonym(syn) = word
    }
}

private void putSynonymTable(String word, String synonymOfWord) {
    Set syns = synonymTable.get(word);
    if (syns == null) {
        syns = new TreeSet<String>();
        synonymTable.put(word, syns);
    }
    syns.add(synonymOfWord);
}

}
```

Try this, It'll give you all the synonyms. If this is not you are looking for then ask for ....

Comment: Thank you.:) i ll check n let u know:)

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by simpler code. I didn't get you.

Comment: Ask me. No problem. You just post. Whenever I'm free I'll try to solve and get it to you. OK.

Comment: I have a question...how to check a given word is their in word net or not.

Comment: I didn't get your question, could you explain it.

Comment: Hi, I was little busy with office work, well I'm hearing this wordnet first time. :(

Comment: Yeah...! I've gone through that, yesterday. Tell me what you've done so far. Where you got stuck.

Comment: The question was given a word say for example happy you need to find the similar meaning to that word say joy..using word net..using java code..

Comment: String similarWord = "";
  while (values.hasNext()) {
   String s = values.next().toString();
   boolean validity = runExample(s);
   if(validity){
   similarWord = similarWord + "\t" + s;
   }
   
    /*System.out.println( similarWord.toString());LongWritable*/
   }
   output.collect(new Text(key)  ,new Text(similarWord));
  
 }

Comment: public boolean runExample(String s){
      
       // construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
//       String wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
      String path ="/home/user/Documents/WordNet-3.0/dict";
       URL url = null;
       try{ url = new URL("file", null, path); } 
       catch(MalformedURLException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
       if(url == null) return false;
     
      // construct the dictionary object and open it
      IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(url);
      dict.open();
      
      IIndexWord idxWord;

Comment: Well, give me sometime, I'll let you know, once I got it.

Comment: in s i have a "happy" which i have stored in a text file ..now i have opened the dictionary and i need to get the meaning of the word happy which is stored in 's' with the wordnet(dictionary)..

Comment: public static Set<String> searcher() throws IOException {
          String path ="/home/user/Documents/WordNet-3.0/dict";
       URL url = null;
       try{ url = new URL("file", null, path); } 
       catch(MalformedURLException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
       IDictionary dict = new Dictionary(url);
       dict.open();

Comment: IIndexWord idxWord = dict.getIndexWord("forest", POS.NOUN);
          IWordID wordID = idxWord.getWordIDs().get(0);
          IWord word = dict.getWord(wordID);
             Set<String> hs1=new HashSet<String>();
         //Adding Related Words to List of Realted Words
         ISynset synset = word.getSynset();
         for (IWord w : synset.getWords()) {
             System.out.println(w.getLemma());
             hs1.add(w.getLemma());
         }
         return hs1;}}

Comment: Ooh... Good. Today I didn't get time to work on it. Had client call. Well. You got it.  : D

Comment: Hi Good Evening:)
How are you:)

I am Exploring Hadoop Ecosystem,with Spark,Elk,but faceing lot of doubts,problems,I am ver much eager to gain more knowledge about it,but need a proper guide.I remember that you told one of your friend is working on Hadooop,Could you please ask him and tell me how to gain knowledge or need to join any institutes,if so which institute to join.Please Please Please Please Please help me.

Comment: Hi,
I'm fine, Thanks.
How are you.
I'll ask my friend today evening, and inform you.

Comment: Ohh... Sorry.
I forgot. I'll ask him.

Comment: My pleasure, 
Are you from hyd..?

Comment: No ,from Bangalore

Comment: Ok, But we are from hyd. And my friend said that he has no idea on institutions. He got trained by his superior.

Comment: Senior. you can reach me at saikiranjgl@gmail.com

Comment: Hi,Your name is  saikiran and the email which you had texted contains the name saikiranjgl@gmail.com..

Comment: Is that your mail-id

Comment: Hi,you told that your friend got trained on big data by his superior ,and you told to reach me at saikiranjgl@gmail.com.. n when I asked about the email id ,you told that mail id is yours..To whom, should I contact ..

Comment: Wohhh....
Sorry for raising unnecessary confusion, and I'll ask my friend for his superior's mail id or something. But we don't know how he replies whether he is free or not. Well hope for the best.

Comment: Hi Good Evening..)

Comment: I Have a question on PigScript Equivalent to sql could I ask:)

Comment: Ok ask. I'll see n let you know.

Comment: Sorry ,I just got it..Thank you:)

Comment: Hi Good Afternoon:)

Comment: I have a question on d3.js.. how to construct the bar graph vertically..here is my code which I have tried..

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

Comment: .d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

Comment: </head>

<body onLoad= "myData()">

</body>
<script>

var json;
function myData(){
 $.ajax({
  url:"http://localhost:8080/ProjectTrials/webapi/users",
  datatype:"json",
  type:"GET",
  success: function(dataset){
   json = dataset;
   alert("success");
   
   
  $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));
 
 var data = json.slowServices;
 
 
 var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

Comment: var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 5]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("top");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("left");

Comment: var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong> Top services: </strong> <span style='color:red'>" +((d.resp_out_timestamp)/100)+ "</span>" + "</br>"
       +"<strong> serviceid: </strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.serviceid+ "</span>"+ "</br>"
       })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", height + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("width", width + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

Comment: x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.serviceid; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.resp_out_timestamp; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Total transaction");

Comment: .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return x(d.serviceid); })
      .attr("height", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return y(d.resp_out_timestamp); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return height - y(d.resp_out_timestamp); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)



function type(d) {
  d.resp_out_timestamp = +d.resp_out_timestamp;
  return d;
}

 
  }
 });
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: Hi,Good afternoon, it's difficult to copy above code, could you mail me that code to saikiranjgl@gmail.com

Comment: sure  Thank you  :)

Comment: Sorry I want the graph horizontally .. I have constructed horizontally but their is some problem with x and y axis.. i have sent the code to gmail..could you please help me..

Comment: Fine, I got mail, but we are missing with data, so could you share some sample json data, so that I can work on it.

Comment: "slowServices" : [
  {
   "serviceid" : "resource-v2",
   "resp_out_timestamp" : 272.20001220703125
  },
  {
   "serviceid" : "GenericAccountDetails-2_0",
   "resp_out_timestamp" : 177
  },
  {
   "serviceid" : "JanrainCapture-1_0",
   "resp_out_timestamp" : 34
  }
 ]

Comment: I've sent a reply with current output, read the mail and reply.

Comment: Hi Good Morning..Thank you so much..I too getting the same output..but change is that I need the range that is 0,20,40 ...to start from the left with the bar graph..

Comment: A small change now I have send the code to gmail..everthing is fine ..but not getting two bar graph but there is a space left for the graph..but graph is diappearing..could you please help me..

Comment: Ooohh yeah!,
I got it.

Comment: I got it:) but the color appears to be black though i change the color..

Comment: Hi, I getting bar charts in ascending order ..could you please tell me how to get in descending order..

Comment: Add this line `data.sort(function(a, b){ return a.resp_out_timestamp>b.resp_out_timestamp;});` after `var data = json.slowServices;` .we are sorting array based on time stamp. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: Mention not, Hope requirement is fulfilled. :)

Comment: Hi Good Morning.. yeah requirement is fulfuilled  :)

Comment: Requirement fufilled..No words to express my gratitute:)

Comment: Ok, It's my pleasure to serve. Glad to hear this from you.

Comment: Hi GoodAfternoon:)

Comment: I have a question on line graph in d3.js..I have send the code which i have tried  along with  the problem description..could you please have a look at it..

Comment: Ok, I'll check in my free time. I've sent you a hang out invitation to ping me there. Ok, we should not make more comments here.